# Remove Quotation from HTTP reponse(string datatype) to pass in post API

Tags: http, power-automate

I have an API returning data(string format) like this

84, 101, 115, 116

But when I call this in power automate the response I get thru HTTP post is with quotation marks

"84, 101, 115, 116"

Is there any way I can get it without  quotation mark " ", As I need the output to send in another API which fails if I send it

with "".

The reason being it needs to pass the response to another API that accepts byte array

like this [84, 101, 115, 116]

currently, inflow it is being sent as  ["84, 101, 115, 116"] which fails the API

I tried replace function but it doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split up your texts into an array.

Start with initialising three variables as shown below ...

[image: Flow 1]

... as you can see, I initialised a string variable with your values, it doesn't show the quotes but it's declared as a string so when it treats it, the quotes will be there.

In the next steps, I initialise an array variable that has the following expression ...

```
split(replace(variables('Response'), ' ', ''), ',')
```

... and then a blank array that will store the resulting number values.

After the above, loop through each value that was found and add it to the number array, this will convert the value as a string to a numeric value.

[image: Flow 2]

The expression above is ... `int(item())`

That then produces this result and it's that array that can then be passed through to your next API call.

[image: Result]

This is the JOSN definition that you can load into your own tenant to see the answer in its entirety.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Number Array",
                            "value": "@int(item())"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('String Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Number_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Number_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Number Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_String_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_String_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "String Array",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@split(replace(variables('Response'), ' ', ''), ',')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize__Response": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize__Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Response",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "84, 101, 115, 116"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@variables('Number Array')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```